# ios Swift Program app to delete things from parse after x amount of time?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Im creating an ios app using parse and swift. I want a users post to delete itself after x amount of time from the server. Is it possible to do this ?
Similar to how snapchat stories disapear after 24 hours.

i was thinking within the app i would make posts only visible if they were posted withiin the alotted time frame. That stops people from seeing old posts. I understand that i would then need something called cloud code to delete the posts. is this correct and how would i go about doing that.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can query through, get the createdAt date of the parse object and compare it to the current time, then delete it if its overdue.

wherever the data is retrieved, if they are user posts, you can put the query wherever you load the user posts. Once any one person tries to load that data and it's too old, it will be deleted and no one will see it.

Comment: if I helped do you mind marking my answer as a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using Cloud Jobs.

> Sometimes you want to execute long running functions, and you don’t
>   want to wait for the response. Cloud Jobs are just meant for that. read More [https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-jobs]

Example :

```
 // REMOVE A MOMENT VIDEO AFTER 24 HOURS
    Parse.Cloud.job("remove", function (request, status) {
      var date = new Date();
      var timeNow = date.getTime();
      var intervalOfTime =  1*24*60*60*1000;  // 24 hours in milliseconds
      var timeThen = timeNow - intervalOfTime;

      // Limit date
      var queryDate = new Date();
      queryDate.setTime(timeThen);

      // Query Moments
      var query = new Parse.Query("Moments");
      // Query the Moments after 24 hours
      query.lessThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", queryDate);

      query.find({
        success: function (results) {
          console.log("Moments: " + results.length);

          // Delete Moment
          query.each(function (object, err) {
            object.destroy({
              success: function (object) {
                console.log("Successfully deleted: " + object.objectId);
              },
              error: function (error) {
                console.log("Error: " + error.code + " - " + error.message);
              },useMasterKey: true 
            })
          })
        },
        error: function (error) {
          console.log("Error: " + error.code + " - " + error.message);
        }
      });
    });
```